# Social Buttons for Bootstrap not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter

i'm creating a website but i'm having some problems with Social Buttons.

I've added the necessary links:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

and added the button, but the design that appears is really weird:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-twitter">
 <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
 Sign in with Twitter
</a>
```

[But the color only goes half way, so it's half white and half blue.](http://postimg.org/image/4jowe6y8z/)

Any idea on what is causing it?

Thanks!